# Centralized MAC filter for wireless lan

Tags: networking, firewall, router, gateway, bridge

I am attempting to install a MAC filter in between a switch that handles my wireless network and the core of the network. The idea is to have a centralized MAC filter bypassing the filters built into the individual access points. My proposal is that wireless devices would still be able to use network resources. How can I effectively do this using Ubuntu 10.04? I have a old dell that I am testing on right now with 2 NICs. I know you can do anything in the world with Linux... soooooo how should I go about this? I would greatly appreciate tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

A good place to start would be as follows.

You could enable ip_forwarding in Ubuntu to make it route traffic:

`echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/default/forwarding`

`echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/all/forwarding`

Then use `arp` to set up static entries (manually filtering):

`arp -s address hw_addr`

`man arp` for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Enable Forwarding:

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

Set iptables FILTER/FORWARD chain to drop everything.

```
iptables -t filter -P FORWARD DROP
```

Add static entries to the FORWARD chain for MAC addresses you want to route into the network.

```
iptables -A FORWARD -m mac --mac-source FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF -j ACCEPT
```

Add an entry to the forward table to allow traffic from already established connections.  This will make sure that the returned traffic can be routed back to the wireless LAN.

```
iptables -I FORWARD -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

As long as you add each MAC address that you want allow routing for, this should work.

Note that this answer doesn't account for the required routing infrastructure.  When forwarding packets across interfaces, it's assumed that you're traversing to a different subnet.  If you're bridging the NICs so they're on the same network; this solution will not work since you're no longer routing packets.

Comment: If I can set up my linux box as a router while still being able to access shared files on the main network, I would be interested in it. Can you walk me through what I would need to set up? Maybe even a link to a tutorial. I'm familiar with Linux but I don't have an intimate knowledge of the networking side. Please help, thank you.

Comment: Setting up a true routed environment would be somewhat tricky unless you already had some routing protocols up and working.  The simplest solution would be to setup NAT from wireless to wired.  As long as nothing from the wired network plans to go back to the wireless network, you can use NAT.  If you want full connectivity in the wired -> wireless direction you need real routing.  To setup NAT/PAT `iptables -t POSTROUTING -A OUTPUT -o {ethX} -j MASQUERADE`.  NOTE: *{ethX}* <- replace with wired facing interface.